# Adding a youtube overlay (for a specific channel) to a Google MAP using the Map API?

Tags: google-maps, youtube, geolocation

Is there a way to add a youtube overlay for a specific CHANNEL (not just an individual video) to a Google Map using the map API?

I can add a flickr feed using the following code:

```
 var kml = new GGeoXml("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photoset.gne?set=MY_SET_NUMBER&nsid=SOME_OTHER_ID_INFO_HERE&lang=en-us&georss=true");
 map.addOverlay(kml);
```

You can just copy the RSS link from your flickr set and paste it where the URL is above, and add "&georss=true" to it...providing you have geotagged your photos.

Is there a way to get the geotag information for a set of videos from a youtube channel in a similar fashion?

Comment: +1 interesting question. I didn't realise you could simply use a flickr rss feed to create a GGeoXml object. I thought it had to be a kml/kmz file. Maybe if a channel doesn't work, trying a PlayList, which would be closer in nature to a Flickr set than a YouTube channel.

Comment: I discovered that youTube doesn't really have a GeoRSS (yet) so I've resigned myself to created a JSON-type file to hold my list of youTube geo-tagged videos.